# android, UWB and BlueTooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I need to write some application on android, which will transfer data to other devices. I need to use UWB protocol to transfer this data and BlueTooth as Data Link Layer. Honestly, I really dont need to do 100% of UWB using BlueTooth. I just need to create something with should looks like UWB. Please dont ask me why I do this in such a way, I just need to do this like that :P.My problem is that I really dont know how can I do that. UWB is pretty new technology and there is not to much about it on the internet, all what I found is only technical description. Do anyone of you have some experience with something like that. Could you give me me some tips how this should looks like. Maybe some of you do something like that or know some good teaching stuff about UWB. Thanks for every tip and help.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, so you probably solved your problem. If you still need help, your best bet is either Bluetooth or wifi. In which case, refer to the Android API for that.

But if you still need to use UWB, there are different ways to implement this. If you are unsure of what you need, here's a helpful table:

[image]

First thing is that you should make sure that the device you are using supports UWB. I am not sure if you can just use the Android wifi API or if you would write a wrapper for it. Some vendors are working on this. Like Samsung:

http://phandroid.com/2012/01/12/samsung-demoes-ultra-wide-band-wireless-usb-technology-ces-2012/

If your device is not supported and more of a hack would be to connect a USB dongle and use the Android USB API to connect to the UWB.

I hope this helps.